# How to turn off UIWebView horizontal bounce

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, zooming, bounce

Simple problem, I have a webview that is supposed to hold just an image for the user to be able to zoom in and out.  To keep my look clean, I want to completely disable bouncing on this view, but still allow scrolling.  This solution does work for the vertical bounce, but as soon as I zoom the image to a size larger than the screen, horizontal bounce is still possible:

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews 
{
    if ( [[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] )
    {

        ((UIScrollView*) subview).bounces = NO;
        ((UIScrollView*) subview).alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
        ((UIScrollView*) subview).alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
        ((UIScrollView*) subview).bouncesZoom = NO;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The following code did the trick for us to stop bouncing:

```
NSString* scriptToPreventBouncing = @"<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } </script>";
NSString* footerHTML = @"<div>All rights reserved</div>";
[footer loadHTMLString: [scriptToPreventBouncing stringByAppendingString:footerHTML] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com"]];
```

I am not sure if this will disable the zooming of image. But it should stop the bouncing.

Comment: That did stop the zooming and scrolling entirely

Comment: worked great!  Now I'm just writing because 2 words aren't enough for stack overflow to like that I like your answer.  ;)

Comment: This solution is really simple! It deserves a lot of reputation points!

Comment: Could one of you explain this a little more ?  Where should I put this?  - and what are the other parts besides the script for? Why is there a div involved?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

On iOS 5 you can solve your problem this way:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] ....];

webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

NOTE: this will work only on iOS5 and higher

Comment: For me, this does not prevent horizontal bounce.

Comment: Correction, this was only for Twitter.com